# How to set jupyter notebook to slides using reveal.js

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown, slideshow, reveal.js

I am trying to make slides using Jupiter notebook, so I can have code embedded on it.

I followed reveal.js to create an html slide.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOpcxy0RA1A

But in the end, I do not get the arrows to switch from one slide to the other

```
google-chrome MySlide.slides.html 
firefox MySlide.slides.html
```

I did the same, but I am not sure why I am not getting slides with arrow presentation. I am getting the whole page at once.

What I am doing wrong? How do I get the presentation with the arrows? I am using ubuntu 18.04

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not seeing the slides as you are directly opening the `html` file in your browser.

Instead, convert your `.ipynb` file from the command line as:

```sh
jupyter nbconvert MySlides.ipynb --to slides --post serve
```

Then to see the slides, including navigation arrows, in your browser navigate to:

```sh
http://127.0.0.1:8000/MySlides.slides.html#/
```

Jupyter should prompt you to navigate to this address by printing to `std_out` something like

`Serving your slides at http://127.0.0.1:8000/MySlides.slides.html`

If you want to view your slides with reveal.js regardless of whether you're serving locally or not, you can do so by pointing to an external reveal.js install:

```sh
jupyter nbconvert MySlides.ipynb --to slides --reveal-prefix  "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reveal.js/3.3.0"
```

Comment: I will accept this because it solved my problem. I also found it easier to install rise https://github.com/damianavila/RISE